# Different Postmaster Emails for different Zoo Visitor group registrations

Tags: zoo-visitor, postmaster

I have several zoo visitor registration forms - one for each of three different member groups. I need to set up different notification templates in Postmaster as the custom fields for each type of member are very different.

I'm using Hooks instead of Parcels as Parcels didnt send on registration - only for update.

Unlike Parcels, Hooks dont appear to have any way to select member groups or statuses so I cant see how I can trigger the relevant hook.

I tried `{if member:group_id == '6'}TRUE{/if}` in the Extra Conditionals field but it does nothing - the notification goes out whether the member group ID is correct or not.

Any ideas?